# get records having admission date in a range

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Using Hibernate I want to get clients ID from  Contract table where the admission date is in a range( between two dates).

```
List clients =  session.createQuery("from Contract contract where contrat.datesouscription BETWEEN "+ begindate+" and "+endate).list();
```

my query doesn't work.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around your dates

```
List clients =  session.createQuery("from Contract contract where contrat.datesouscription BETWEEN '"+begindate+"' and '"+endate+"'").list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query with parameters, as buiding queries via concatenation is not recommended due to security reasons (opens up the code to SQL injection attacks):

```
String hql = "from Contract contract where contrat.datesouscription BETWEEN :beginDate and :endDate";
List result = session.createQuery(hql)
.setParameter("beginDate", begindate)
.setParameter("endDate", enddate)
.list();
```

Have a look at these [examples](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/).